# how to initialize a jquery.js file from a .phtml file?

Tags: magento2

In I want to initialize my jquery.js file into a possible .phtml file? Which path do I have to use? i'm using a geito so far but it doesn't seem to work. I'm inside a template file and I want to initialize the jquery at the end of the footer. How could I do this?

What am I using:

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Require js

in your phtml:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            'jquery'
        ], function ($) {
//here you now can use $ jquery :)


    })
```

Comment: that's not what I need. I need to load the javascript library via phtml file, using <script src"??"> I need to know the path.